# No "renameat2" system call function on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, glibc

The man page for [`renameat2()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/renameat2.2.html) says I need to include `<stdio.h>` but this does not work.

When I do a

```
cd /usr/include
grep -r renameat2
```

I see that the __SYSCALL is defined but no glibc function. The flags for the system call are available in `<linux/fs.h>` but this is not included.

Comment: What version of glibc do you have? What version of the Linux kernel?

Comment: Linux kernel is 4.4 (the syscall was added in 3.10)
Glibc version is 2.23

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay i found the answer here, the general problem with glibc not adding system calls and the man page missing the

> Note: There is no glibc wrapper for this system call; see NOTES.

note which is shown on other pages. So i got confused.

Found the answer by reading this article
https://lwn.net/Articles/655028/

And this is the code

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

//Open the old directories to obtain fds
int src_fd = open("old_dir", O_PATH);
int dest_fd = open("new_dir", O_PATH);
const char* src_path = "old_name.txt";
const char* dest_path = "new_name.txt";

unsigned int flags = RENAME_NOREPLACE;
int rc = syscall(SYS_renameat2, src_fd, src_path, dest_fd, dest_path, flags);
```

Comment: *An Update from the Future*: The system call wrapper for this function is included starting in glibc 2.28 released in 2018-08-01. It didn't make it in time for 18.04LTS so the `syscall`-method will stay with us the next 8+ years anyway…